# Raising exceptions in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to report errors from my rcpp code. I am using the constructor `exception (const char *message_, const char *file, int line)` from http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/classRcpp_1_1exception.html. To isolate the problem, I wrote the following `bar.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

RcppExport SEXP bar( SEXP x){
        throw(Rcpp::exception("My Error Message","bar.cpp",4));
        return x ;
}
```

When I run it in R, this is what I get:

```
> dyn.load("bar.so")
> is.loaded("bar")
[1] TRUE
> .Call("bar",12)
Error: SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'NULL'
>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can either

- use the [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) package which puts a `try`/`catch` block into the function it generates for you (by using two simple macros)
- or do it manually yourself as shown in a bunch of examples on my blog, or in the examples/ section of the [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) package,

but doing what you (ie: throwing outside of a try/catch block) can never work.

As an added bonus, here is a complete example (which essentially already existed in the unit tests):

```
R> library(inline)
R> f <- cxxfunction(signature(), plugin="Rcpp", body='
+    throw std::range_error("boom");
+    return R_NilValue;
+ ')
R> f()
Error in f() : boom
R>
```

Again, `cxxfunction()` puts a `try`/`catch()` block in here for you as you can see if you turn `verbose` on:

```
R> f <- cxxfunction(signature(), plugin="Rcpp", body='
+    throw std::range_error("boom");
+    return R_NilValue;
+ ', verbose=TRUE)
 >> setting environment variables:
PKG_LIBS =  -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib \
            -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib

 >> LinkingTo : Rcpp
CLINK_CPPFLAGS =  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"

 >> Program source :

   1 :
   2 : // includes from the plugin
   3 :
   4 : #include <Rcpp.h>
   5 :
   6 :
   7 : #ifndef BEGIN_RCPP
   8 : #define BEGIN_RCPP
   9 : #endif
  10 :
  11 : #ifndef END_RCPP
  12 : #define END_RCPP
  13 : #endif
  14 :
  15 : using namespace Rcpp;
  16 :
  17 :
  18 :
  19 : // user includes
  20 :
  21 :
  22 : // declarations
  23 : extern "C" {
  24 : SEXP file4cc53282( ) ;
  25 : }
  26 :
  27 : // definition
  28 :
  29 : SEXP file4cc53282(  ){
  30 : BEGIN_RCPP
  31 :
  32 :    throw std::range_error("boom");
  33 :    return R_NilValue;
  34 :
  35 : END_RCPP
  36 : }
  37 :
  38 :
Compilation argument:
 /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD SHLIB file4cc53282.cpp 2> file4cc53282.cpp.err.txt
ccache g++-4.6 -I/usr/share/R/include   \
   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   \
   -fpic  -g0 -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -c file4cc53282.cpp \
   -o file4cc53282.o
g++ -shared -o file4cc53282.so file4cc53282.o \
   -L/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib \
   -lRcpp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/lib \
   -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
R>
```

The `BEGIN_RCPP` and `END_CPP` add the magic you need here.

Please *do* move your questions to rcpp-devel.

Comment: Thanks! from the examples, do you mean `copyMessageToR` and `Rf_error` as used in RcppDateExample.cpp? I couldn't find documentation for `copyMessageToR`.

Comment: Aah ... but asking here seems to work just fine, yielding excellent answers within minutes, after all! Catch my drift? ;)

Comment: Yes. That is what you use in the `catch()` block.

Comment: @Dirk, does rcpp-devel really have people responding quickly? My experience with specialized mailing lists has been either people not responding or responding with "read the docs". Usually, the reason I am asking is a) I didn't find the "right" docs, or b) the solution doesn't exist in the docs. In which case I'm looking for people have used any alternatives to get something like that done. Because at the end of the day I am not interested in knowing if Wizwoz 2.0 has the feature, I want to see if someone knows something that can get the job done. sorry for the rant. will chk out devlist.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, so is the dev-list more moral because it takes longer, or is it because the developers want to know of use-cases and problems. I haven't gone over to rcpp-devels because I didn't think my problems were development related. They were more user-centric. But I'd really like to know the reason why one or the other forum is better. I am not trying to be funny, I am really just asking a question.

Comment: @highBandWidth - Naw -- morality doesn't even enter in.  My comment was really a friendly jab at Dirk, who is clearly (to all of our benefit) compulsively helpful.  That said, the response times over at rcpp-devel do look pretty good, and you'll often get answers from the package author himself -- especially if you post them around midnight.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, the output from this on my system is `Error in f() : c++ exception (unknown reason)`.

Comment: Then you threw an exception type that is not derived from the base type, henceno text conversion. Maybe look more closely at my example.

Answer (score 4):

Just wrap your code inside `BEGIN_RCPP`/`END_RCPP`:

```
RcppExport SEXP bar( SEXP x){
BEGIN_RCPP

        throw(Rcpp::exception("My Error Message","bar.cpp",4));
        return x ;

END_RCPP
}
```

Note that you can throw normal std exceptions too:

```
throw std::invalid_argument("'x' is too short");
```

Comment: Even after adding `BEGIN_RCPP` and `END_RCPP`, `Rcpp::exception` still gives the same `STL_VECTOR_ELT` error. `std::invalid_argument` throws an exception, but the message displayed in R is a generic `Error: c++ exception (unknown reason)`.