# More info on Rcpp exception

Tags: r, exception, rcpp

When writing R extensions using Rcpp is it possible to get more information when an exception is thrown?
For instance by default when an index is out of bound I get:

```
Error in myfunction(V) :
  index out of bounds   
Calls: source ... eval -> myfunction -> .Call -> cpp_exception
Execution halted
```

at this point I have no idea where in the code it might have happened. When compiling the code with debug information is it possible to print the stack? Can the Rcpp exception do that?

On a segfault I guess I can try to use [deathhandler](https://github.com/vmarkovtsev/DeathHandler), but I am also looking for a solution for regular exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

That one is most likely not from your code / Rcpp code.

If you use Rcpp for exception, you coontrol the and recover the message at the R level (provided you derive from `std::exception` etc).  There a number of example out there as e.g. [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438701/raising-exceptions-in-rcpp).

But to catch 'random' errors like this, you may need to resort to using the debugger.

Comment: I am fine with using gdb, but how do I tell it to stop on the Rcpp exception? Can I put a breakpoint on the Rcpp exception? Is there a way to register exception handlers?